# Unit testing: Call @PostConstruct after defining mocked behaviour

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, postconstruct

I have two classes:

```
public MyService {
    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;     
    private List<Items> list; 

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
         list = myDao.getItems(); 
    }
}
```

Now I'm wanting to involve `MyService` in a unit test, and so I'll mock the behaviour `MyDao`.

XML:

```
<bean class = "com.package.MyService"> 
<bean  class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"> 
     <constructor-arg value="com.package.MyDao"/>
</bean>

<util:list id="responseItems" value-type="com.package.Item">
    <ref bean="item1"/>
    <ref bean="item2"/>
</util:list>
```

Unit Test:

```
@ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired 
    MyService myService

    @Autowired 
    MyDao myDao;

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("responseItems")
    private List<Item> responseItems; 

    @Before
    public void setupTests() {
        reset(myDao); 
        when(myDao.getItems()).thenReturn(responseItems); 
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the `MyService` bean is created, and its @PostConstruct bean called before the mocked behaviour is defined.

How can I either define the mocked behaviour in the XML or delay `@PostConstruct` until after the unit test setup?

Answer (score 25):

I have same kind of requirement in my project. where i need to set a string using @PostConstructor and I did not want to ran spring context or in other words I want simple mock. My requirement was follow:

```
public class MyService {

@Autowired
private SomeBean bean;

private String status;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    status = someBean.getStatus();
}
```

}

Solution:

```
public class MyServiceTest(){

@InjectMocks
private MyService target;

@Mock
private SomeBean mockBean;

@Before
public void setUp() throws NoSuchMethodException,  InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    when(mockBean.getStatus()).thenReturn("http://test");

    //call post-constructor
    Method postConstruct =  MyService.class.getDeclaredMethod("init",null); // methodName,parameters
    postConstruct.setAccessible(true);
    postConstruct.invoke(target);
  }

}
```

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: perfect solution.

Answer (score 4):

MyDao sounds like it is an abstraction of an external system. Generally external systems shouldn't be called in `@PostConstruct` methods. Instead have your `getItems()` called by another method in `MyService`.

Mockito injections will take place after the Spring initiation at which point the mock isn't working as you see. You cannot delay the `@PostConstruct`. To beat this and have the load run automatically have `MyService` implement `SmartLifecycle` and call `getItems()` in `start()`.

Comment: Yeah - I think you're probably right, that generally my problem indicates a code smell that I should solve.