# How can I mock value for a bean when it is initialized in @PostConstruct

Tags: java, unit-testing

When I mock a bean and assign value that initialized in @PostConstruct. It always run first so can not be assigned.

Comment: please post the code too

Comment: Hi, my problem is similar with this post.
https://github.com/cdi-unit/cdi-unit/issues/64

Comment: Try to use @InjectMock, Let's me know the result

Comment: thank you for your help, I found answer in this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175822/unit-testing-call-postconstruct-after-defining-mocked-behaviour